# Custom security is not working when extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class in different package

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have extendend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in a different package other than the package containing class for `@SpringBootApplication`. Then it's not working its generating default username and password.

And it's working fine when it's in the same package.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

class extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
package com.securitymodule;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.configure(http);
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and().formLogin();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.configure(auth);
        auth.
        inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }


}
```

Comment: As documented. When running the application it will scan all packages and sub packages of the class itself. So it will scan `com.example` and everything underneath that. `com.securitymodule` isn't underneath `com.example` and thus doesn't get scanned.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum . Your comment helped me alot. It worked for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`@SpringBootApplication` is a short hand for `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan`. This makes Spring to do componentscan for the current packages and packages below this. So all classes in `com.example` and under `com.example` are scanned for bean creation while not any others above `com.example` like `com.securitymodule`

Hence either add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.securitymodule"})` into your main class, or make the package of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as `com.example.securitymodule`